# Matlab - Graphical user interface (GUI), plot with arduino data

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, arduino

i have a Matlab program done with a real time plot that acquire data from a LDR sensor with arduino.
Now i want to implement that program in a GUI and i'm facing some problems with ploting. Here is the part of my program that i dont know how to plot in GUI mode.

> (...)
>   While(1)
>   state = a.analogRead(0);
>   (...)
>   axis tight
>   drawnow;
>   x = [x, state];
>   plot(x,'-*b');
>   grid on;
>   end

The code must be in the OpeningFcn? Should i just copy paste the into there? What do i have to change in the ploting code? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neverending `while` loop in `OpeningFcn` will indefinitely lock up your GUI. You're better off creating a timer object and running your 'continually' plotting code code in its callback; an example:

```
function myui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

    % Create timer with delay of 0.1 seconds
    handles.tmrPlot = timer( ...
        'ExecutionMode', 'FixedRate', ...
        'Period', 0.1, ...
        'TimerFcn', @myPlottingFunction);

    % Store in ui data
    guidata(hObject, handles);

    % Start it!
    start(handles.tmrPlot);
end

function myPlottingFunction(src, evt)
    % Do some plotting
    plot(rand(10));

    drawnow;
end
```

With a timer you can also, for example, start and stop the execution in the callback of a button.